How to install XnView MP on Ubuntu 24.04
Attempt1: Installation via App Center
I've downloaded XnViewMP-linux-x64.deb and opened with App Center, as result I've got an endlessly loading page
Attempt2: Installation via terminal
$ sudo dpkg -i XnViewMP-linux-x64.deb 
[sudo] password for serg: 
Selecting previously unselected package xnview.
(Reading database ... 193120 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack XnViewMP-linux-x64.deb ...
Unpacking xnview (1.7.2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xnview:
 xnview depends on libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0); however:
  Package libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 is not installed.
 xnview depends on libopenal1 (>= 1.14); however:
  Package libopenal1 is not installed.
 xnview depends on libxcb-xinerama0; however:
  Package libxcb-xinerama0 is not installed.
 xnview depends on libopenal1; however:
  Package libopenal1 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package xnview (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1.1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.27-2build1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 xnview

When I'm trying to install dependencies I get errors:
$ sudo apt install libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libopenal1 libxcb-xinerama0 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 : Depends: libgdk-pixbuf-xlib-2.0-0 (>= 2.40.2-3build2) but it is not going to be installed
 libopenal1 : Depends: libopenal-data (= 1:1.23.1-4build1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libsndio7.0 (>= 1.8.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Maybe somebody know how to manage these dependencies?
Update:
BTW it helped me:
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install


Maybe somebody know how to manage these dependencies?

In general, you can never be sure that a .deb package will and can be correctly installed on your distribution. In this case, you have downloaded a package that clearly has not been prepared for installation on Ubuntu 24.04. As an end-user, your only reliable option will be to alert the developer that the .deb file does not install on the current LTS of Ubuntu (and hence likely also not on recent versions of Debian).
Maybe someone will come by with a solution to work with the current .deb, but it will be quite technical. Because this is not free and open source software, downloading the source code and compiling it yourself is not an option. Still, even if you could, it can be very difficult to cope with missing dependencies.

How to install XnView MP on Ubuntu 24.04

First, always consult the website of the application developper. For XnView MP, an appimage is made available as an alternative installation option.
There are two easy alternative ways:

As an appimage:  This will be the most obvious way to use that application on Ubuntu. For Appimages to work on recent Ubuntu versions, you need to install libfuse2 first.

The application is available as a flatpak on flathub. Flatpak is not installed on a default Ubuntu install, but can easily be enabled.


